# ASP.NET MVC ModelState validation for masked email

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, email

I have this model with an email property as below:

```
[Required]
[EmailAddress]
[Display(Name = "Email")]
public string Email { get; set; }
```

Then i wanted to display this to the view as myemail at example dot com. So before i pass on the model to the view i formatted the email.

My problem is when it get posted back after some changes, the ModelState.IsValid will now fail because its not a proper email format. Even if i reformatted the email back to myemail@example.com before calling the ModelState.IsValid, it will still fail.

How will i do this?

I have 2 options in mind, first, remove the attribute EmailAddress so it will be treated as string. Second, use this ModelState.Remove("Email"). Second one will remove the required validation i think.

Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So before i pass on the model to the view i formatted the email.

In that case, don't format the `Email` property directly and instead have another property (non-required/optional) in your model say `public string FormattedEmail { get; set; }` and use that property to hold the formatted email and use the same in your view.